# Appending a list

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append the "result" variable into a new list called total_winnings but I get an error.

I managed to do it successfully for the total_stake but I get an error when I try use the same method for `total_winnings`.

I think it is because the "result" variable takes string input?

```
while True:

    add_selection =raw_input("Would you like to add a selection?")
    if add_selection == "Yes":

        selection = raw_input('Horse: ')
        print selection

        stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
        print stake

        odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))
        print odds

        result = (raw_input('Result: '))
        if result == "Win":
            print stake * odds
        elif result == "Lose":
            print 0 * odds


        book = raw_input('Book: ')
        print book

        my_list=[selection,stake,odds,result,book]

        inputs.append(my_list)

        total_stake=[]
        for my_list in inputs:
            total_stake.append(my_list[1])
        print sum(total_stake)

        total_winnings = []
        for my_list in inputs:
            total_winnings.append(my_list[3])
        print sum(total_winnings)

        def looks_good(inputs):
            for i in inputs:    
                print i                       

    elif add_selection == "No":
        break

    looks_good(inputs)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add complete code including `inputs` initailization and `looks_good`

Comment: "but i get an error" And... the error is a secret? :-)

Comment: My guess is that the error is on the line `print sum(total_winnings)` and that it  tells you the issue is that your list has strings in it instead of integers.

Comment: I'm guessing one of your `inputs` does not have the index 3.

Comment: Please add the error message to your post

Comment: vaibhav bajaj sorry i posted the q last night then went to sleep

Comment: sorry i cant remember what the error was but it was int and unicode nxt time ill remember to write the error yes smarx that what it was i used the result_val solution below it worked perfectly thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my_list[3] contains either Win of Lose i.e a string value and summing over it won't work. You can do something like this

```
result = (raw_input('Result: '))
    result_val = stake*odds
    if result == "Win":
        print result_val
    elif result == "Lose":
        print 0
```

And while adding to my_list, simply add the result_val instead of result or in addition to result

```
my_list=[selection,stake,odds,result_val,book]
```

Comment: Yes is there any differnce thought with the one above you have just put the result_val above the if and post1 has got it after the if, it works either way, thanks!

Comment: @JJBridger yes there is, my code updates your result_val as stake*odds for any value of result i.e win or lose because it is not within the conditions.
Whereas , the code below updates result_val as stake*odds for win and 0 for Lose.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

The problem is that you are currently storing strings `"Win"` and `"Lose"` in `my_list[3]` whereas you mean to store `stake * odds`. When you do the function `sum(my_list[3])`, it gives an error as it cannot sum up strings.

To fix the error, change the `if else` statement from:

```
if result == "Win":
   print stake * odds
elif result == "Lose":
   print 0 * odds
```

to:

```
if result == "Win":
   print stake * odds
   result = stake * odds
elif result == "Lose":
   print 0 * odds
   result = 0
```

Comment: My error was int and unicode. Yes this solution works great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (raw_input('Result: '))
```

`result` is a `str` (a string).

```
my_list=[selection,stake,odds,result,book]
...
for my_list in inputs:
    total_winnings.append(my_list[3])
```

`my_list[3]` is `result`, which is a `str`. If you print out `total_winnings`, I think you'll see something like `["Win", "Lose", "Lose"]`.

```
print sum(total_winnings)
```

Now you're trying to `sum` those strings. This doesn't make sense, and presumably it gives you this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I think you meant to do something like this:

```
result = (raw_input('Result: '))
if result == "Win":
    result = stake * odds
elif result == "Lose":
    result = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see several issues with your code.

First, defining a function ("def looks_good(inputs)") 
within a loop is not a good idea. Unless you're trying
to do something relatively tricky, function definitions
should be at the top level of your code, before
other stuff.

Second, the variable named "inputs" is used in 
"inputs.append(my_list)" before it is defined
anywhere.

Since you are using the same name ("inputs") in
as an argument for the looks_good() function,
you are setting up a situation where there are 
two different "inputs" variables - one inside
the function and one outside - which is almost
certainly a bad idea. Using different names
for those different variable scopes may help.

Fix those issues first, and then see if your
error message is any clearer. If it still isn't
working, I'd suggest putting in lots of "print"
statements to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Sorry I didnt post the proper code inputs is an empty list before the loop